# Show that the sums are equal to:

Tags: analysis, summation

a) If $\sum_{k=1}^∞ \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{π^2}{6}$ show that  $\sum_{k=1}^∞ \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2} = \frac{π^2}{8}$

b) Show that $\sum_{k=1}^∞ \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)} = \frac{1}{4}$

Hint for b): Find A, B, C so that for ∀k:
$\frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}$= $\frac{A}{k}$ +$\frac{B}{k+1}$+ $\frac{C}{k+2}$

I managed to do a) but don't know how to do b)

a) $\sum_{k=1}^∞ \frac{1}{k^2}$ -  $\sum_{k=1}^∞ \frac{1}{(2k)^2}$ =   $\sum_{k=1}^∞ \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}$

$\sum_{k=1}^∞ \frac{1}{k^2}$ -  $\sum_{k=1}^∞ \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{k^2}$ =  $\frac{π^2}{6}$ - $\frac{1}{4}$$\frac{π^2}{6}$=$\frac{π^2}{8}$

Comment: Well.  $\sum_{all}-  = \sum_{even} +\sum_{add}$ and $\sum_{2k=2}^\infty \frac 1{(2k)^2}= \frac 14\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{k^2}$

Comment: Although I think that's supposed either $\sum_{k=\color{red}0}^{\infty}\frac 1{(2k+1)^2}$ or $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{(2k\color{red}{\large -}1)^2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find the constants $A,B,C$, they are $\frac{1}{2},-1,\frac{1}{2}$ respectively, then you term

$\frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}=\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{2(k+2)}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1})+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{k+2}-\frac{1}{k+1})$ if you take the series (Harmonic series) you limit is $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{4}$.

Recall that $\sum_{1}^n (a_{k+1}-a_{k})=a_{n+1}-a_1$ then $\sum_{K=1}^{\infty}(a_{k+1}-a_{k})=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{1}^n (a_{k+1}-a_{k})=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n+1}-a_1$